# how do i get ios device token in Ionic

Tags: ios, ionic3, apple-push-notifications, devicetoken

I'm working with ionic 3, APNs (not other) and want to get the IOS device token.

If token can be generated with APNs, please refer the source, If not by APNs how do I generate them.

Comment: you can use device id for this. get by this plugin in ionic v3 - https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/device/

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the [Firebase X](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/firebase-x) Plugin. Information about the Ionic 3 Usage can be found [here](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-firebasex#ionic-3). You can get the APNS Token with this Plugin.